# How can I make an infinite scroll with jquery, ajax and html files

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I am trying to make an infinite scroll effect by using jquery, ajax and html files that I created and uploaded to a cloud storage. I am a beginner and just started learning coding.

** Below is part of the code that I am experimenting with. When I use the current code I have the content is duplicated unless I add  $(window).off("scroll.once"); to stop the function from repeating.

*** **CURRENTLY** *** -  The scroll event requires you to reach the bottom of the page, then an ajax request is made and it pulls the content from the html document I uploaded to my cloud drive.

After appending the content of the html file to the Main Tag, if I scroll back to the bottom the page, the function & ajax call is repeated and the content of the html file is duplicated.

*** **GOAL** *** - Each time the function is completed, I want the url to automatically updated so that the content of the next html file in my cloud storage can be appended below the previous content. I also need to be able to tell the function, how many times to updated the url and reinitialize.

**URL Examples for 3 different files:**

1st HTML file URL - Anywebsite.com/HTMLl

2nd HTML file URL - Anywebsite.com/HTML2

2nd HTML file URL - Anywebsite.com/HTML3

```js
$(window).on("scroll.once", function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ENTER FIRST URL",
            success: function(data) {
                $('main').append(data);
            },
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>Test</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the the html file names numbered per your question then you can use following code to achieve your desired results. Be noted that this is just to give you the idea how to change the url, the code will start given error when it reaches number no html file exist i.e for html4 you'll get 404 response if it does not exist on the location.

```
var step = 1;
var loading = false;

$(window).on("scroll.once", function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
        if(loadding === false){
            loading = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Anywebsite.com/HTML'+step,
                success: function (data) { step++; $('main').append(data); loading = false; },
                dataType: 'html'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! 

If I was to add $(window).off("scroll.once"); to the last html file. Would that stop the function from continuing past the last htmls url?

Comment: Yes you can set condition to meet a criteria in your last file to set the scroll off

Comment: I just attempted to initialize the revised code and I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @ZubairAhnd I was able to get to code to initialize, however the url does not update. Only the 1st html's content is appended but not the 2nd or 3rd.

Comment: How do you know url was not updated? there are multiple reason its not working for you, that include the your step var is gets over written. If proper structure of your html is not know reasons can not be ruled out.

Comment: After you mentioned the structure of the html I doubled back to review my work and discovered a mistake on my end. The revised code snippet you provided works perfectly now! Thank you!

Comment: @DCMCODING glad I was able to assist

Comment: I changed the 3rd line in the code snippet to the following code `  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 900) {  ` to change the distance needed between the bottom of the page and before the Ajax call is triggered, however now the page appended content gets duplicated. I've been reading articles on setTimeout() method but I'm not sure how to implement this, or if it would fix the issue.  Would you have any ideas on a solution?

Comment: I am updating the code to include how to prevent multiple requests initiating

Comment: The updated code you provided loads the first htmls content via url and does not duplicate, however now the second urls content doesn't load at all.

Comment: have you noticed that I added loading = false; after apend data ? did you copy that too. cuz after apending  the data it must be set to false again so that ajax is triggered when scrolled

Comment: I got it working correctly.  Everything you suggested was correct. The issue was a line of code that was in the html files disrupting the function. After I removed the line of code all url links loaded and there was no duplicated content! Thank you, for all your help.

Comment: @DCMCODING glad I was able to assist

Comment: Hello @ZubairAhmd, 

Hope all has been well. I was wondering if you could assist me with a minor issue i am having with the snippet of code you provided, in our earlier conversation.


When the ajax request is called on Safari Browser on iPhone, an unknown error occurs.

Comment: @DCMCODING, I am fine good thanks. Does it happen start form the beginning or during subsequent calls? Never had issue with this code on any device. Try disable the code snipt to rule out if this code is source of issue.

Comment: the error happens during subsequent calls. I’ve only noticed the issue when using iPhone. The code seems to be working properly on android and desktop running windows.

Comment: @DCMCODING this means that first call works fine and error happens when you try to get next data. This shows that your 1st call returned successfully but you dom is updated with something invalid element that cause the next call to throw error and its vendor specific element. Disable UI update on response and try sending request again. if request succeed then my theory is confirm. you need to check what are you updating on response and with what.

Comment: I'm new at coding and I don't know how to disable UI update on response.

Comment: @DCMCODING comment out this line $('main').append(data);

Comment: When I comment out $('main').append(data);, the infinite scroll doesn't work and no data is appended. However when I comment out  loading = false; the 1st html file will append correctly without any errors but the second file doesn't load.

Comment: @DCMCODING when you comment loading=false; it will never make the second call cause call is subject be made when loading = false; any how it seems that my prediction about bad data in response is cause issue after 1st page load. as you already said that 1st page loads fine. You need to analyze the data returned in response. check what it contains. looks like its have bad data causing issue.

Comment: You are right. I tried implementing infinite scroll using a different set of html files and everything worked perfectly. Which means there is bad data in one of the html files being appended.  Thank you!

Comment: @DCMCODING glad it helped. If you intended to send html data in response it is always a good idea that html is tested prior to including in any response. I normally create static html check output then included that html in any response data.

Comment: I'm definitely going to take your advice on the static html check moving forward.